# With Statement Ignored unless run in debugger

Tags: python, django

I am using django-tenant-schemas and am attempting to build an administration panel for all my tenants under my Public tenant.

However the following view isn't executing properly:

```
@login_required
def users(request, tenant_pk):
    tenant = get_tenant_model().objects.get(pk=tenant_pk)
    with tenant_context(tenant):
        users = User.objects.all().order_by('username')
        context = {'tenant':tenant, 'users':users}
    return render_to_response('tenant_management/users.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The desired result is that it will retrieve the tenant based on the url parameters and give me a list of all the users that belong to that schema. The tenant is retrieved properly, but instead of showing me the users in that schema it is showing me the users in the public schema.

Now the part that gets weird is that if I insert a break point after the with statement or execute the entire function in my debugger, then it works perfectly as expected.

Here is a picture of the results:

[image: Expected Results: Only shows when debugger is run]
This is the expected result. It shows all 3 of the specified tenant's users properly. This only happens if the debugger is run past the 'with' statement.

[image: Unexpected Results: Displays Public schema users]
This is the result if I run the code without the debugger or if I let the debugger continue before the 'with' statement.

Here is the output of my immediate window when I am debugging:

```
# Debugging before the with statement
> tenant = get_tenant_model().objects.get(pk=1)
> tenant
<Tenant: Public>
> User.objects.all()
[<User: d>]
# While debugging after the with statement:
> tenant
<Tenant: Tenant 1>
> tenant.pk
2
> User.objects.all()
[<User: test1>, <User: test2>, <User: test26>]
> context['users']
[<User: test1>, <User: test2>, <User: test26>]
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with PyTools as my IDE. I get the same results whether I use the Visual Studio 2013 built in runserver with debugging or if I use the command 'python manage.py runserver', so I don't think it is a problem with my IDE.

Edit: For reference here is the code for the tenant_context()
https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas/blob/master/tenant_schemas/utils.py#L25

```
@contextmanager
def tenant_context(tenant):
    previous_tenant = connection.tenant
    try:
        connection.set_tenant(tenant)
        yield
    finally:
        if previous_tenant is None:
             connection.set_schema_to_public()
        else:
             connection.set_tenant(previous_tenant)
```